# Nested Table Not Expanding HTML

Tags: html, formatting

I'm starting to learn html and am working at using tables to make some simple layouts. I understand this is quite an old way of doing things, but would like to understand them anyway, if only for gaining a better understanding. I'm currently trying to create a nested table, but the table data element I would like to fill the remaining area of the larger table is not expanding. My simplified html is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="400" align="center" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><h1>Site</h1></td>
        <td><img src="diameter.png" height="40" width = auto></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table border ="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Menu List</td>
                    <td>blah</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">cell1</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

I am trying to change the td with blah in it to fill up the remaining space in its td, but when I try width=100% it simply makes the height greater ; not affecting the width at all. Changing it by pixel values works, but then it would not update relative to the larger table.

What is causing this? Is it elements being too close together? Thanks for your help in advance